# Return current day in Android Studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Kotlin in Android Studio and want to show the user the current day at the home screen (of my "app"). Following the Build your first app tutorial I figured I would change the message it displays to what I want (the day), however I don't know how to get the current day.

Searching online I found the `fun getDay(): Int`
function in the documentation but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Your `getDay` method does only work with Javascript, not with Java (Android).

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-date/get-day.html so the JS at the top shows its only for javascript?

Comment: Exactly, just click on the "JS" button and the method will not be shown anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below to get the current day:

```
fun getCurrentDay(): Int {
    val value: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    return value.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
}
```

It should return the current date in a week(1-7).

You could also use other constants to fill in .get()

- [DAY_OF_MONTH](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Calendar#day_of_month)
- [DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Calendar#day_of_week_in_month)
- [DAY_OF_YEAR](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Calendar#day_of_year)

I haven't tested the code yet, but hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`, eg. 12 for today.

Another possibility would be `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` for weekdays.